# .htaccess rewrite rule to subfolder if is specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, server, url-rewriting

I need some help with my .htaccess file specifically with a rewrite rule

My directory structure:

```
root
├── plans
│   │── .htaccess
│   │── app 
│   └── public
└── Wordpress
```

The result what I want:

If the user goes to the directory https://localhost:8888/plans/
The htaccess file rewrite this to the subfolder **public** (https://localhost:8888/plans/public)

What I tried so far

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /public/ [L]
```

This gives my a 404 error not found.

Is this possible and how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule in `plans/.htaccess`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!public/)(.*) public/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will rewrite all paths in `/plans/` to `/plans/public/`. `(?!public/)` is a negative lookahead to stop rewrite if URI is already `/plans/public/`.